# Unable to build an image using Dockerfile

Tags: docker-build

Here is the error I'm facing, could someone help me out on this?

```
free(): invalid pointer
SIGABRT: abort
PC=0x7f78f73a4f47 m=0 sigcode=18446744073709551610
signal arrived during cgo execution
```

Comment: error when building docker usually comes from environment. And you need to make sure every environment is included in the requirement. Pls attached the Dockerfile also

Comment: FROM python:3.7-alpine
WORKDIR /code
ENV FLASK_APP app.py
ENV FLASK_RUN_HOST 0.0.0.0
RUN apk add --no-cache gcc musl-dev linux-headers
COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt RUN pip install -r requirements.txt COPY . .
CMD ["flask", "run"]

Comment: pls add to the post instead

Answer (score 2):

You need to install these packages

```
sudo apt install -y gnupg2 pass
```